# Getting updated columns from table excluding few columns updates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Help on this scenario to get desired result set.

A table contains 10 columns among them 3 columns are count field,'updated date' & 'Created Date'. This table have values updated or created using a SP in that SP, we will compare the input table and output table entire row if matches then we will update the updated date to the run date and increment count field. If not matches then we will insert into a new column in the output table.

My requirement is I need know how many rows got updated irrespective to two fields in that table. eg. Table having first name, last name , phone no and fax no and emp id. I need to know count of rows updated irrespective to phone no and fax no.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give sample data and what is your expected output

Comment: Hi.  Can you provide [sample data, and expected output](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  Also if you have a query (event if it isn't working) please add that.  The community is more likely to help if they see you've put some effort in (which I'm sure you have).